# In what music genre is The Coconut Song?

Tags: genre

Recently, I stumbled upon a funny song on Youtube named "[The Coconut Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0AOGeqOnFY)" (alias Da Coconut Nut - by Smoky Mountains) and I couldn't quite figure out what music genre is it writen in.

**What's the genre The Coconut Song is in?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most strong characteristic (and despite some possible other minor influences introduced by the choir arrangement) is that of **[Calypso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calypso_music)**, a traditional genre from the Antilles, because of:

- syncopated rythm
- call and response structure
- vocal oriented with multiple voices (in this case is a pure choir performance, but several voices at work in Calypso is common, even if there is intrumental accompaniment)
- it's subjective, but the melody suggests the Calypso to me
- the obvious accent of the lead singer and the thematic of the coconut

One of most famous calypsos (perhaps the most famous) is the [Banana Boat Song by Harry Belafonte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMigXnXMhQ4). Despite Belafonte's rendition being slower and more relaxed than the Coconut Song, the similarities seem pretty obvious to me.

*Thanks to Chris Sunami for confirming the genre attribution and helping to make the answer more clear.*

Comment: +1 I wouldn't be tentative about the genre identification, this is definitely calypso.  There's actually a very similar "[Coconut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9eY2LFAn-4)" calypso song that Belefonte himself does.

Comment: I suppose you're right @Chris, some of the harmonies used sound to me at bit too modern for the genre, but perhaps I was overly cautious. I'll improve the text.

Comment: @ChrisSunami - Please do not post comments containing "+1", "-1", or "Thanks".  Excessive comments like this can put this community to an end.

Comment: @MaikaOshikkoSakuranomiya While I appreciate your initiative, I'm not aware of any ban on comments *containing* +1", "-1" or "Thanks."  What is discouraged is comments consisting *entirely* of such content-free markers or approval or disapproval, since those are redundant with the voting system.  I'd also note that the Stack Exchange community is experiencing [much deeper problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology) at this point in time...

Answer (score 3):

The genre may be calypso but the composer (and the accent of the soloist) is Filipino. The song was released as a pop single in the 1990s by the group Smokey Mountain, which was mentored by Ryan Cayabyab, the composer. The choral arrangement is ca. 2008.